# Фон для блока с помощью переменной (jQuery JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Пытаюсь сделать смену фона через jquery с помощью переменной:

```
var bbb = $(this).closest('.colTwo').find('.productData').text();
```

//Winter Dress

```
$(this).closest('.productItem').children('.colOne').css({
        backgroundImage : 'url(../image/' + bbb + '.png);'
});
```

Не срабатывает хотя путь по DOM дереву верный. Когда захожу в браузер то он не ругается на то что картинка не найдена, а ***строка со стилем не добавлена***.

**В чём может быть проблема?**

Comment: Попробуйте написать .css({ 'background-image' : 'url(../image/' + bbb + '.png);'});

Comment: @humster_spb спасибо попробовал. Но работает только при условии что склеивание строк будет происходить вне кода `css()`.

Comment: А что значит "вне кода"? У Вас сейчас склеивание происходит как раз в коде css(). CbIPoK2513 показал ниже как это работает.

Comment: @humster_spb  Я имел ввиду что если написать такой код `bbb = 'url("./image/' + bbb + 'Green' + '.png")';
  console.log(bbb);
  $(this).closest('.productItem').children('.colOne').css({
   'background-image' : bbb
  });` Всё работает в отличии от варианта когда это делается внутри функции .css(), то бишь вне кода ( за скобками )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`backgroundImage` не работает. Прописывайте `'background-image'`

```js
let bbb = 'https://i.imgur.com/Le4SNI2.png';

$('.two').css('background-image', `url(${bbb})`);
$('.one').css(backgroudImage, `url(${bbb})`);
```

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red center center / cover;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test one"></div>
<div class="test two"></div>
```